# Obtaining value of tkinter Entry field for using (locally) in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI, and something is going on with the variables.

It starts with calculating a value theta, which when I click a button, gets passed to an Entry field (this is written in a function: `thetaVar.set(CalcTheta(grensVar.get(), data[:,1], data[:,2]))`).

```
thetaVar = IntVar()

def callbackTheta(name, index, mode):
    thetaValue = nGui.globalgetvar(name)
    nGui.globalsetvar(name, thetaValue)

wtheta = thetaVar.trace_variable('w', callbackTheta)
rtheta = thetaVar.trace_variable('r', callbackTheta)

entryTheta = Entry(textvariable=thetaVar).place(x=90, y=202)
```

This works (and I see the value in the Entry field), but when I later try to obtain this value, it does not work.
I believe I tried everything:

```
thetaVar.get()   # with print, returns the integer 0, this is the initial value 
                 # that is displayed, even though at that moment it shows 0.4341.
thetaVar         # with print, returns 'PY_VAR3'
thetaValue       # with print, global value not defined
entryTheta.get() # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
rtheta           # print returns: 37430496callbackTheta
```

I do not understand where this value is stored and how I can use the value of the entry in another function. Even when I try any of these right after the actual `.set`, I cannot seem to print this specific value of the Entry right after.

Using tkinter and Python 3.3 on windows 8.

Comment: I listed the things I tried. Please see the second block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the value of an entry widget:

1. you call the `get` method on the widget, eg: `the_widget.get()`
2. IF you have a textvariable assigned, you can call the `get` method on the textvariable, eg: `the_variable.get()`

For either of these to work, you must have a reference to either 1) the widget, or 2) the textvariable.

In your code you are making a common mistake, which is to combine widget creation and widget layout. This results in `entryTheta` being set to `None`.

When you do something like `foo=bar().baz()`, what gets stored in `foo` is the result of the final function, `baz()`. Thus, when you do `entryTheta = Entry(textvariable=thetaVar).place(x=90, y=202)`, `entryTheta` is set to the result of the call to `place` which will always be `None`.

The simple solution is to call `place` in a separate statement (and you should also seriously reconsider the use of `place` -- `pack` and `grid` are much more powerful and will give you better resize behavior.)

Comment: Wooooh! Thanks a lot! I would have never guessed. Note that I can obtain the value now from the widget, but the thetaVar.get() still prints to 0, while the entryTheta.get() does print to the right value

Comment: I am using place now for convenience of showing a first version. I am assuming I will have to rework the whole layout, and will then reconsider pack and grid. Thank you.